Estimating errors on negative mass spec intensities
I am writing mass spectrometry (specifically, residual gas analysis with a quadrupole mass spec) data reduction software and have come across an interesting problem.
My primary goal here is to calculate errors on the intensity measurements provided by the QMS, which reports intensities $y$ in current or $A$. I assume these errors to be a Poisson distribution with respect to the number of electrons $N$ counted over the dwell time $t$:
$$N = \frac{yt}{q}$$
where $q$ is the charge of an electron.
The error on the intensity $\sigma_y$ is therefore
$$\sigma_y = \sqrt{\frac{yq}{t}}$$
The problem is what to do with negative intensities reported by the QMS. Baseline intensities, for example, are frequently negative on some systems when measuring blanks, meaning errors on these negative intensities are going to be critical for propagating the baseline correction error.
Is there an established methodology for calculating errors in negative mass spec intensities?
For further information, I am calculating errors on these intensities for the purposes of fitting them back to a time $t=0$ to determine the theoretical peak intensity $y_0$. Adding errors to these fits would yield more robust regressions.
EDIT: A little more detail about our analytical process:
We are primarily measuring $^3$He and $^4$He, with auxiliary measurements of ${^2}$H and ${^{40}}$Ar to keep an eye on the health of the vacuum system. We finally measure at ~5.5 amu, where no gaseous species exist, as the baseline.
The baseline correction is the mean of the intensities at 5.5 amu throughout the analysis measurement period. This correction is applied after the individual errors on intensities are estimated via Poisson, but before the individual intensities are fitted to determine $y_0$.
EDIT: More analytical details.
We are using Pfeiffer Prisma-series QMS devices. These use Faraday detectors with a secondary electron multiplier (SEM) to amplify the signal. Signals are reported in amperes of current on the detector.
Unfortunately, what's going on with the signal before it's reported is somewhat of a black box and therefore we can't really say what the error function truly is. I am merely attempting to estimate the errors in order to improve my curve fitting.
An image of the curve fitting I'm talking about to add to the discussion below:


I'm certainly no expert on this field, but root mean square (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) might work…

Most quadrupole MS systems I'm familiar use highly nonlinear, amplifying detectors such as dynodes, multichannel plates, or similar.  Your application sounds more similar to isotope ratio mass spectrometry, and if so, maybe it uses a Faraday cup detector.  Either way this is a good article to check out.  I don't think it will be possible to say how to handle negative intensities without understanding what the "units" of MS signal are, i.e., what is the detector.

And also what the MS instrument itself (software and firmware) is doing to the raw signal before it reports "counts" or whatever arbitrary unit it reports, to you.

A previous answer on a different stackexchange website (physics) nailed this problem, however, their answer seems to have been deleted. I will attempt to reproduce it here.
I HAVE EDITED THE BELOW TO INCLUDE $y_\text{stray}$.
As comments have pointed out, negative intensities come from the fact that the error in the system is not only Poisson-based.
Consider that raw measurements $y'$ consist of the true intensity of desired counted ions $y_\text{true}$, the un-desired intensity of stray ions hitting the detector $y_\text{stray}$, and instrumental noise $\epsilon$.
$$y' = y_\text{true} + y_\text{stray} + \epsilon$$
While $y_\text{true}$ and $y_\text{stray}$ are Poisson distributed and thus $\geq0$, $\epsilon$ may cause small values of $y'$ to be negative.
Because we lack independent measurements of the stray ions and noise, we must estimate both from the baseline measurements $b$, measured at 5.5 amu where no gaseous species exist. We therefore approximate that:

The noise term $\epsilon$ is normally distributed around 0, with error $\sigma_b$:

$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_b)$$

The intensity from stray ions $y_\text{stray}$ is the baseline mean, $\bar{b}$, with Poisson-based errors.

When $y' \gg \epsilon$, we assume that $y_\text{true}$ is the baseline corrected value $y$, or
$$y = y' - \bar{b}$$
however, when $y' \approx \epsilon$ or $y' < 0$, we use a Bayesian approach to estimate $y_\text{true}$ given the prior knowledge that $y_\text{true} \geq 0$. The probability of observing $y_\text{true}$ given a noisy measurement $y'$ is given by:
$$P(y'|y_\text{true}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\varepsilon^2_{y_\text{stray}} + \sigma_b^2)}} \exp\left(-\frac{{(y' - y_\text{true} - \bar{b})}^2}{2(\varepsilon^2_{y_\text{stray}} + \sigma_b^2)}\right)$$
The posterior probability of $y_\text{true}$ given $y'$ is:
\begin{equation}
P(y_\text{true}|y') = \frac{P(y'|y_\text{true})P(y_\text{true}}{P(y')}
\end{equation}
where the denominator, $P(y')$, is:
\begin{equation}
    P(y') = \int_0^\infty P(y'|y_\text{true})P(y_\text{true}) dy_\text{true}
\end{equation}
The error in $y_\text{true}$, denoted $\varepsilon_{y_\text{true}}$ is then based on the Poisson counts, making the error in $y$:
$$\varepsilon_y = \sqrt{\varepsilon^2_{y_\text{true}} + \varepsilon^2_{y_\text{stray}} + \sigma^2_b}$$

I'd be more concerned with what it means for noise to produce a negative amplitude if the detector is generating counts. If I count birds in flight then occassionally I might register a plane as a bird but what would register as a "negative bird"?

Does the inclusion of the term $y_\text{stray}$ resolve your concerns? This way we are not counting anything negative.

Negative baselines and intensities do not have a physical meaning in instrumental analysis. It is an artifact of "autozero" when the measurements start. A mass spectrometer is counting ions, so the intensities cannot be negative by definition. At the start of an analysis, the instrument's software must have applied a zero setting, perhaps electronically or digitally, i.e. so with time, the negative values are nothing but "noise" fluctuating around that artificial zero. All the background counts are still positive.
In short, the baseline wander must be corrected before applying any statistics. See Whittaker based baseline correction methods Baseline library which work pretty nicely.
I think the proper way of noise analysis would be starting with noise analysis of the experimental data of the blanks after baseline correction. Once the baseline has been corrected, then estimate the noise distribution by histograms. Does it actually follow Poisson statistics? Most likely not, because after all the digital filtering and noise suppression which is going on in these black-boxes, the noise distribution would be most likely Gaussian. The manufacturers don't tell any detail, no matter how many times you ask. Their filters are their trade secrets.
Another point, which some hardcore analytical chemists would state, is that, the signal to noise must be calculated "at the peaks", i.e., measure the peak intensities 10-30 times. The standard deviation of the peak intensity, is the noise and your average peak height is the signal.

Thanks for shedding some light on this! While the true errors are likely impossible to accurately fully account for, my thought was that a Poisson distribution would at least give me a number less than the true errors but account for the quantifiable part of the error in a way that would ultimately improve my curve fitting routine.

As for your last paragraph, my program actually fits the curves of the data according to consumption/ionization or ingrowth from memory, rather than applying an average. The error of the fitted $y_0$ intensity at $t=0$ is easy to estimate based on the quality of the curve fit, however, the errors on individual intensities is what I'm after.

Interesting. I am very much interested in noise reduction problems. What kind of peak functions are you using? With ref. to the average, it was directed at signal to noise measurements of individual intensities. The problem at hand is not trivial. It cannot be generalized.

There is room for improvement and I am open to suggestions but basically the algorithm applies an initial linear fit and checks the $R^2$ and slope. If $R^2 \leq 0.3$, I do use the bulk average and standard deviation. When $R^2 > 0.3$, if the slope is negative, I apply an exponential decay curve $$y = a \exp(-pt) + b$$ to model consumption and when positive, I use a log-linear model $$y = a \ln(t + t_{eq}) + mt + b$$ where $t_{eq}$ is the equilibration time offset to model ingrowth from memory.

Sorry, I thought you are doing peak modeling of MS. There is a very useful software with hundreds of peaks called PeakLab. https://aistsw.com/

The software writer is an acquaintance, and it would not be wrong to say that nobody knows more about curve fitting than this gentleman with 30+ years of experience in curve fitting and modeling functions.

I am doing peak modeling of MS! Unless I am using the term 'peak' incorrectly. We are taking the intensities (peaks) measured at various masses over time and curve fitting them back to a time $t=0$ to determine the original intensity $y_0$, which cannot be measured directly due to gas equilibration time.

I've added an image of the curve fitting I'm talking about to the OP to demonstrate.

Right, this is not peak fitting in a traditional sense. By peak modeling I meant, you actually model the peak "shape". You are looking at peak intensities as a function of time  and trying to model t=0, intensity. Is this correct?

That is correct.

Certainly, this is not peak fitting or modeling. Are the curves being fit with least squares? No harm in checking least absolute deviation fit. Another suggestion is that you look at peak areas as a function of time, instead of intensity. How do the curve look like?
